# Validate compatibility of two XML schemas

Tags: c#, xml, f#, xsd

Is there a .NET call to validate that one XML schema is backwards compatible with another?

Comment: Does that imply a superset/subset relationship between the schemas?

Comment: ...if so, the [XmlDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302295.aspx) API might provide output you could analyze to determine that.

Comment: I believe it implies a superset relationship, yes. The link from that article to the library itself is broken though (http://apps.gotdotnet.com/xmltools/xmldiff/).

Comment: A download link for the installer is at the top of [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx). Looks like the overload of `XmlDiff.Compare` taking a `diffgramWriter` arg might do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

No. You'll have to use the `XmlSchema` class to parse the two schemas and then write code that does the comparison.

XML comparison/differences won't cut it, because two XSD can be even identical and have very different XML representation - e.g.:

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="test">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="str" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="num" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

and

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="test" type="test">
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="test">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="str" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="num" type="xs:int"/>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```